# TensorFlow reshaping with Conv1D

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have seen problems similar to mine here on Stack Overflow, but not exactly the same.  I can reshape when using fully-connected NN layers, but not with Conv1D layers.  Here's a minimal example.  I'm using TF 1.4.0 on Python 3.6.3.

```
import tensorflow as tf

# fully connected
fc = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,12])
fc = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(fc, 12)
fc = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(fc, 6)
fc = tf.reshape(fc, [-1,3,2])

# convolutional
con = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,50,4])
con = tf.layers.Conv1D(con, 12, 3, activation=tf.nn.relu)
con = tf.layers.Conv1D(con, 6, 3, activation=tf.nn.relu)
con = tf.reshape(con, [-1,50,3,2])
```

Here is the output (yes, I'm aware of the RuntimeWarning.  The messages I have found which discuss it suggest that it's harmless, but if you know otherwise, please share!):

```
/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 3.5 of module 'tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util' does not match runtime version 3.6
  return f(*args, **kwds)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 468, in make_tensor_proto
    str_values = [compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 468, in <listcomp>
    str_values = [compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/compat.py", line 65, in as_bytes
    (bytes_or_text,))
TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got <tensorflow.python.layers.convolutional.Conv1D object at 0x7fa67e0d1a20>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "minimal reshape example.py", line 16, in <module>
    con = tf.reshape(con, [-1,width,3,2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 3938, in reshape
    "Reshape", tensor=tensor, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 513, in _apply_op_helper
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 510, in _apply_op_helper
    preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 926, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 229, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 208, in constant
    value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 472, in make_tensor_proto
    "supported type." % (type(values), values))
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.layers.convolutional.Conv1D'> to Tensor. Contents: <tensorflow.python.layers.convolutional.Conv1D object at 0x7fa67e0d1a20>. Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

My code fails at con = tf.reshape(con, [-1,50,3,2]).  Yet the pattern is nearly identical to the pattern that I use for the fully-connected graph, fc.

I made nets very similar to these work in the higher-level API for TensorFlow called [TFLearn](http://tflearn.org/).  However, [TFLearn's DNN Estimator object is having trouble managing a tf.Session correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47500671/tflearn-dnn-evaluate-%E2%86%92-valueerror-cannot-use-the-given-session-to-evaluate).  After over a month, I have yet to [resolve the issue](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/issues/966) with TFLearn's developers on GitHub.

I don't mind using TensorFlow's native Estimator, but I have to solve this reshape problem to achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found the error: **tf.layers.Conv1D != tf.layers.conv1d**.  Changing the former to the latter eliminated the error.  Let the TensorFlow / Python user beware!

Even though TensorFlow seems to avoid Python's object model (which is probably necessary, given the possibility of distributed, low-level computation), there are in fact a few genuine classes in the Python API.  The class constructors can accept many (all?) of the same arguments as the similarly-named convenience functions.